# JSON schema for overrides - best practices

Tags: java, json

I have a use case where I define an object (set of properties) and for some scenarios/criteria, I need to override the set of properties with different values. What is the best way to design the schema.

Below is the sample that I could come up with:

```
{
        "ActionType": "actionType",
        "ActionData": {
          "Template": {
            "version": 1,
            "feedback": "Action Feedback.",
            "Overrides": [
              {
                "criteria": {
                  "allOf": {
                    "Country": "JP"
                  }
                },
                "Template": {
                  "version": 1,
                  "feedback": "Japanese Feedback"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

I have such overrides for different types of objects in the JSON. My main focus is usability - who ever reads the json will have to replace the properties with appropriate overrides. And how would my Java models look like? as I see there would be self-referencing objects.

Comment: If you have different scenarios and different set of properties/values then you have different objects, do not try to use the same for everything

Comment: speaking about self-referencing objects, still you will have only the reference and you will have to use some identifier as Person has id and his responsible (property responsible) will have the identifier of his responsible... so for example person.id=1 and person.responsible=1

Comment: Is this question about JSON Schema the specification (as per the tag description) or just "the structure of your JSON instance"?

Comment: Its just about the structure.